# How is the dominant dragon decided?

Tags: league-of-legends

I tought it was just the last dragon, or the dragon who will spawn the most, but I did a game and got Ocean, Wind, and then on the third dragon it was decided it was a inferno map. And then 3 inferno drakes spawned in a row.

So when and how is the 'dominating' dragon decided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 3 dragons of the game are random and all unique, so you can never have multiples of the same elemental dragon until the map is transformed.
The third dragon which spawns in a game will trigger the map changes and be the only type of elemental dragon that will spawn for the rest of the game.

https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/gameplay/preseason-2020-gameplay-rise-elements

> Rise of the Elements will bring SR to life as the primal magic of the
>   Elemental Drakes changes the landscape each game. The third drake
>   transforms the Rift before it spawns and after that, its element will
>   be the only one to spawn for the remainder of the game.

Comment: slight caveat, the third drake only spawns until one team has taken 4 of them.after that the elder dragon will spawn for the rest of the game

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that comment. The 3rd dragon will only spawn after 4 have been taken? How?

Comment: @n_plum It's confusingly worded if you don't know the mechanics (and probably even if you do in a lot of cases). All drake spawns after the third one will be of the same type as the third drake, until one team has killed four drakes, at which point the elder dragon will start spawning instead. When they say "the third drake only spawns" they really mean "drakes of the same type as the third only spawn".